# Counting how many integers give a integer in the square root

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions, mathematica

My question is about a Mathematica code that gives the same as a mathematical experssion (for integers) but I do not know why.

[The mathematica code is the following](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/201410/find-the-number-of-trues-in-a-trueq-expression) (you can try it out for integers on [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Count%5BTable%5BFractionalPart%5BSqrt%5Bn%5D%5D,%7Bn,%23%7D%5D,0%5D%26%2F@%7B100%7D)):

```
Count[Table[FractionalPart[Sqrt[n]],{n,#}],0]&/@{k}
```

And it gives the same as:

$$\lfloor\sqrt{k}\rfloor\tag1$$

> Why is that true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not super familiar with Mathematica, but it seems that your code asks how many elements between $1$ and $k$ have fractional part zero when taking the square root.

i.e. How many elements are a square between $1$ and $k$. You could also ask the question of how many elements have squares that are less than $k$.

This latter question can be answered by noting that you need only find the largest integer less than $\sqrt{k}.$

i.e. $\lfloor{\sqrt{k}}\rfloor.$